# Textfield gets empty when press return

Tags: flutter, dart

when i press return key in keyboard my textfield gets empty, i have pasted my code below

```
                                   Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2-60,
                                      child: TextField(
                                        onChanged: (String value){
                                          name = value;
                                        },
                                        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                                            hintText: 'Enter your name'
                                        ),

                                        controller:userDetailsModal != null? TextEditingController(text: userDetailsModal.userDetails.name):TextEditingController(text: ""),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

when i searched the issue , i found that it is occurring due to Textfieldcontroller inside build, but i have multiple fields namely mobile,name,location. and i want the functionality as i pasted above code.

how to achieve it

Comment: This is the wrong way to use `TextEditingController`, you should keep It, not rebuild It over and over...

Comment: can you help me to solve my issue

Comment: Just keep It in your `initState` and you would never miss the value. Make a StatefulWidget to wrap It instead of trick It like that.

Comment: can u add the code

Answer (score 0):

As @Tokenyet said, you should not create your controller in the `build` method:

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userName;

  const InputPage({Key key, this.userName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  TextEditingController controller;
  String name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.userName != null) {
      name = widget.userName;
    } else {
      name = '';
    }
    controller = TextEditingController(text: name);

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        name = controller.text;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 60,
      child: TextField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: 'Enter your name'),
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }
}
```